# Instantiate a class using String VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, class, instantiation

I searched already a lot in the Internet but I can't find a way on how I can instantiate a class using a string. can any one lead me the right words/right codes?

What I only know is how I can call a method using a string like this.

```
Dim methodName As String = "aaa"
Dim h As New Helper()

Dim HelperMethods = h.GetType() _
                     .GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance) _
                     .Where(Function(m) Not m.IsHideBySig) _
                     .ToArray()
Dim result = h.GetType().GetMethod(methodName, BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance).Invoke(h, params)
```

Comment: You'll want Type.GetConstructor() instead.  Activator.CreateInstance() is a friendly helper method.  Your snippet doesn't make much sense, you already created a Helper() class object.

Comment: @HansPassant please show me an example...

Comment: Just look at the MSDN Library sample code.

Comment: where? can you give me the link please?

Comment: @Mahan I am also a bit confused on this front. What you want is basically Dim var As Class1 = new Class1() but by relying on a string; something like:  Dim varType As Type = System.Type.GetType("NameSpace.Class1") and Dim varName As varType = new varType(). I am not sure how you can get that (if possible at all). But have seen right now a pretty good Hans Passant's answer and I am sure that he is the most indicated person to solve this doubt...

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know how to accomplish this either. What I mean (and think that Mahan too) is: Dim varType As Type = System.Type.GetType("NameSpace.Class1") Dim varName As varType = new varType() ... I am under the impression that this cannot be done. The closest approach would be something via reflection and invoking methods/fields; but not sure how to instantiate the given class. Could you help a bit here (Type.GetConstructor does not deliver this)?